# Read environment variable in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

What is the best way to read **environment variables** in **SpringBoot**?
In Java I did it using:

```
String foo = System.getenv("bar");
```

Is it possible to do it using `@Value` annotation?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Spring Boot allows you to externalize your configuration so you can work with the same application code in different environments. You can use properties files, YAML files, **environment variables** and command-line arguments to externalize configuration. Property values can be injected directly into your beans **using the `@Value` annotation**, accessed via Spring’s `Environment` abstraction or bound to structured objects via `@ConfigurationProperties`.

So, since Spring boot allows you to use environment variables for configuration, and since Spring boot also allows you to use `@Value` to read a property from the configuration, the answer is yes.

---

For example, the following will give the same result:

```java
@Component
public class TestRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Value("${bar}")
    private String bar;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Foo from @Value: {}", bar);
        logger.info("Foo from System.getenv(): {}", System.getenv("bar")); // Same output as line above
    }
}
```

Comment: What todo If I want to use this in a  `@Entity` class, e.g. for a getter?

Answer (score 67):

You can do it with the @Value annotation:

```
@Value("${bar}")
private String myVariable;
```

You can also use colon to give a default value if not found:

```
@Value("${bar:default_value}")
private String myVariable;
```

Comment: Works only in initialized components, dows not work in main class from static main function.

Answer (score 25):

Here are three "placeholder" syntaxes that work for accessing a system environment variable named `MY_SECRET`:

```
@Value("${MY_SECRET:aDefaultValue}")
private String s1;

@Value("#{environment.MY_SECRET}")
private String s2;

@Value("${myApp.mySecretIndirect:aDefaultValue}") // via application property
private String s3;
```

In the third case, the placeholder references an application property that has been initialized from the system environment in a properties file:

```
myApp.mySecretIndirect=${MY_SECRET:aDefaultValue}
```

---

For `@Value` to work, it must be used inside a live `@Component` (or similar).  There are extra gochas if you want this to work during unit testing -- see my answer to [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49803576/86967)

Comment: Notice the different punctuation `#{` vs `${` when using `environment.`.

Comment: I think you have a typo @Value("#{environment.MY_SECRET}") should be with $

Comment: @dgraf, See the prior comment (by me) -- this is intentional.  It's kind of an obscure feature, but you can find it documented by looking for [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef).

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively, you can use the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` interface to access environment variables (**NOTE**: this works only in initialized Spring components):

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

//...

System.out.println(env.getProperty("bar"));
```

[Read more...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html)

Comment: Does not work on main static function of `@SpringBootApplication` class. Works only in initialized Spring components.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, most answer didn't mention, the ordering is very important, please check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Your `OS environment variables` will overwrite the value come from `Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).`, so basically, your environment variables has higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with the `@Value` annotation for the `@Component`s and `@service` class.

Sometimes it won't work if it is a normal class.

Example:

```
@Component
public class Testclass{
    @Value("${MY_SECRET:aDefaultValue}")
    private String test1;

    @Value("#{environment.MY_SECRET}")
    private String test2;

    @Value("${myApp.mySecretIndirect:aDefaultValue}")
    private String test3;

    //to get the properties list which are in "," separated
    @Value("${my.list.of.strings}")
    private List<String> myList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place your environment variable in an application.yml/application.properties  file and then you can fetch the value using the @Value annotation.
But in order to use @Value annotation your class should be a bean and should be annotated with @Component annnotation.
You can also provide a default value for the variable.

```
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MyClass {
 
@Value("${something.variable:<default-value>}")
private String myEnvVariable;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In rare cases, if you want to access environment parameters in spring `main` methods ( which is static ) you can must let Spring application build then use the `ApplicationContext` to access `environment` . Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).run(args);
    Environment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    System.out.println(environment.getProperty("spring.application.name"));
    System.out.println(environment.getProperty("foo.bar"));
            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers to read the environment in code using `@Value` hence I am not providing that.
Below is the example of using environment variable in `application.yml` file to provide some external values based on different env.

```
my-service:
  api-base: ${API_BASE:}
  env: ${ENVIRONMENT:prod}
```

In the above example, the property configuration will use the evironment variables which could be provided externally during application launch, and they will be replaced in here. It also supports the default value if the env var is not provided, as seen for `env`

Below is my docker-compose.yaml snippet which is providing these variables.

```
services:
  my-service:
    environment:
        API_BASE: http://example.com/api/v1
        ENVIRONMENT: ci
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you have to define the relevant field information in the properties configuration file, and then use @ value to obtain and use
example:

```
@Value("${abc}")
private String abc;
```