# Getting kubernetes secret / env for authentication into java application

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I hava a java `spring.boot` application that uses Kubernetes, I'we configured this `.yaml` file

```
- name: ACTUATOR_USERNAME
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: actuator
      key: username
- name: ACTUATOR_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: actuator
      key: password
```

added this attributes to my `application.propertis`

```
security.user.name=${ACTUATOR_USERNAME}
security.user.password=${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}
```

secret is created at server side, how do I retrieve this values inside my class

```
package com.greenqloud.usage.healthcheck;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("actuator username: " + System.getenv("ACTUATOR_USERNAME"));
        System.out.println("actuator password: " + System.getenv("ACTUATOR_PASSWORD"));

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("actuator").password("{noop}actuator123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

the only way I have found is to use the `System.out.getenv("ACTUATOR_USERNAME")` but I'm sure there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with using `System.getEnv`? What "better way" do you want?

Comment: nothing, I was just under the expression that there where a more `spring.boot` way to achieve this, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am agree with @Kuikiker about getenv(). But one question why do u want to store credential in env variable. Unless u have some special need I believe you will be better off store them in your application.properties with encrypted value. I usually use jasypt encipher for that (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt). 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sure I want what you are suggesting, I have in my `application.proppertis` file 
`security.user.name=${ACTUATOR_USERNAME}
security.user.password=${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}`

How can I retrieve this values inside my java class?

Comment: @Value("security.user.password"). Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: like this
`@Value("security.user.name")
private String actuatorUsername;

@Value("${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}")
private String actuatorPassword;

auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(actuatorUsername).password(actuatorPassword).roles("USER");``

although IntelliJ complains about `Private field 'actuatorUsername' is never assigned` ?

Comment: Yes IDE does that. This value get assigned to the variable on run time through dependency injection so IDE complain because it could not find any reference.

Comment: Why can I not directly use the value like this `auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(@Value("security.user.name")).password(@Value("${security.user.password}")).roles("USER");` ?

Comment: Spring boot only render the object that are part of spring boot component.

Comment: got this error
`2019-02-20 14:42:19.589 ERROR 880 --- [  XNIO-3 task-4] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /actuator/

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
 at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:238) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]`

Answer (score 0):

System.getenv() is used to retrieve environment variable values; there is nothing wrong with it. However, since you are using SpringBoot you may find the following question valuable: [Read environment variable in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803211/read-environment-variable-in-springboot)