# Spring profile based on environment variable

Tags: spring, environment-variables, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Boot application running on a JBoss EAP Server. Is there a way to load up a Spring profile based on environment variable set in the Linux Operating System?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read environment variable in SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803211/read-environment-variable-in-springboot)

Comment: @pvpkiran It doesn't say how I can load a Spring profile based on an environment variable.

Comment: Just set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable or pass it as an argument when starting the program using `--spring.profiles.active`

Comment: @M.Deinum I can only develop my application and provide a war file to the team that deploys it. I can't set any environment variables or provide extra parameters when starting the JBoss server. I can only use what's already available.

Comment: If you have a war you should have extended the `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override/implement the `configure` method. In this method check the environment variable, when set, add that as active profile in the `configure` method.