# How to pass Windows Authentication details to react application

Tags: reactjs, windows, spring-boot, authentication, iis

I have built a react web application for a client that is hosted on Windows Server 2016 in IIS (configured with windows authentication)  I can see the www-Authenticate Negotiate response header and when I look at the IIS logs I can see my username in the cs-username field.  Is there an easy way to pass the client user's details from the web server to the react client application so I can display a user's information or is this going to require building a custom .Net app to handle?  I'm pretty new to SSO, Active Directory and Windows Auth so I'm looking for the easiest solution possible

Comment: Since you have IIS, most people would consider making "a service" or "web api" using .NET, but there are other technologies which would work.  Are there any server-side languages that you already know, or tech standards at your org? Might want to start there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.  I actually have an API built to feed the app.  It's a Spring Boot application so it's java.  I can write a .Net app in C# if I have to, but I was hoping there was an easier way to pass the information back either as a response header configured in IIS or as a part of my existing spring boot API.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I would expect Spring Boot should be able to get that info. It might be an environment var https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803211/read-environment-variable-in-springboot.  In .NET or CGI it is in Request.ServerVariables.  Spring Boot must have something equivalent.

Comment: How is your app deployed/served in IIS?  Is it CGI, or Managed, or using NSSM or something?  (eg. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-deploy-spring-boot-application-on-a-Windows-server)

Comment: The react application is just the default website on iis.  The spring boot API isn't deployed on IIS, it is deployed as a jar file which runs in the background as a windows service with WINSW (a windows service wrapper)

Comment: In that case, you could either use .NET or you could even get that info via a CGI script. Those examples should be easy to find, and simple.  I could paste one below, if you don't care about the technology, or search for something you find likeable.